# Rename lists without overwriting data in R

Tags: r

I would like to rename my nested list names to the same name without changing the underlying data.

Here is my example list:

```
#Create dataframes ABC.123 and ABC.987, where 'left' and 'right' columns are numeric and the 'up' column contains characters
ABC.123 <- cbind.data.frame(left = c(2, 3, 5), right = c(5, 8, 4) , up = c("aa","aa", "aa"))
ABC.123$up <- as.character(ABC.123$up)
ABC.987 <-  cbind.data.frame(left = c(7, 2, 9), right = c(3, 6, 1) , up = c("bb","bb", "bb"))
ABC.987$up <- as.character(ABC.987$up)

#Create a list called mylist, containing two dataframes: ABC.123 and ABC.987
mylist <- list(ABC.123 = ABC.123, ABC.987 = ABC.987)
$ABC.123
#  left  right  up 
#1  2     5     aa  
#2  3     8     aa
#3  5     4     aa  

$ABC.987
#  left  right  up 
#1  7     3     bb  
#2  2     6     bb
#3  9     1     bb
```

I would like my output to look like this:

```
perfect.list
$ABC
#  left  right  up 
#1  2     5     aa  
#2  3     8     aa
#3  5     4     aa  

$ABC
#  left  right  up 
#1  7     3     bb  
#2  2     6     bb
#3  9     1     bb
```

And with a simple name change, the underlying data changes, and I am trying to avoid this, which I see when I click on mylist in the RStudio Environment Window:

```
names(mylist) <- c("ABC", "ABC")
mylist
$ABC
#  left  right  up 
#1  2     5     aa  
#2  3     8     aa
#3  5     4     aa

$ABC
#  left  right  up 
#1  2     5     aa  
#2  3     8     aa
#3  5     4     aa
```

I can get the perfect.mylist output if I apply the name change and type "mylist" directly into the console window, but again if I click on mylist in the RStudio Environment, it shows overwritten data. So, I am prompting a bug, and I don't know which is correct.

I am ultimately going to do.call(rbind) the nested lists with the same name, if that helps answer the question of why I am doing this. If I am prompting a bug, is there a better way to combine my nested lists?

Comment: Have you double checked in a fresh R session? Just running `names(mylist) <- c("ABC", "ABC")` works fine for me and doesn't alter the data.

Comment: @joran, thanks for the suggestion. I just cleared my environment, and I re-ran the code just from my example above with same results. I am using R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10) -- "Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out" and RStudio Version 1.3.1093, if that helps.

Comment: Have you tried actually restarting R entirely? Because I'm just not seeing the same behavior your are.

Comment: @joran, yes, I just restarted RStudio entirely. When I re-ran the code from my example, I click on mylist in the Global Environment, I see the incorrectly overwritten list as per my example above. But when I type "mylist" in the console window, it returns the correct re-naming. So, which one is correct, and why don't they show the same results?

Comment: This sounds like a bug in RStudio's environment display code.

Comment: mylist$ABC points to two different elements of list mylist, this is generally not a wise idea.- probably causing the write over of $ABC

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the information that you see different results in the console and in the environment pane, and add the `rstudio` tag?

Comment: I'm not seeing it either, and I'm using the same versions as you (on macOS).  This is both in the console and the environment pane.

Comment: @user2554330, are you looking in the console or in an RStudio environment pane (or both)?

Comment: I suspect @BenBolker is right and that R is actually doing what you want and the problem is merely in the RStudio UI, being confused by list elements with the same name. However, I don't see the behavior you describe in the Environment pane in RStudio either, so updating RStudio would also be a thing to try.

Comment: Ok, the *only* place I see the wrong behavior is if I click on the object in the Environment pane, which then opens a new tab in the script editor pane and if I click on the individual elements *there* I see the wrong data displayed. This is definitely merely a UI bug in RStudio.

Comment: @joran, yes, I see the same as you.

Comment: @BenBolker, I edited the question to reflect the difference in my output to the console, which is what I want, compared to the output in the RStudio Environment pane, which is not what I want. So, which is correctly displaying the changes: the console or through the Environment pane?

Comment: The console is correct. The object is what you want. This is a problem with the RStudio UI. There's no way for us to "fix" it; you could report it to them as a bug.

Comment: Thanks, @joran. Since, I am newer to SO, what do I do now with my question that has morphed into something entirely different and is now containing useful comments about what-NOT-to-do when renaming, but the question itself does not need to be answered?

Comment: This is actually a known old bug in RStudio:  https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2966.  What should you do?  You could delete it if you think it's not going to be helpful to anyone, but I think it should be kept.  So you could write up an answer pointing to this bug report, or if someone else does, you could accept their answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments by @user2554330 and @joran, what I'm trying to accomplish in my question prompts a well-known, well-documented bug in RStudio:  https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2966.

In this case, trust the console output, which accurately reflects any manipulation to the data objects. And just know what you see in the RStudio Environment pane is not an accurate representation of your data objects.

And overall, try to avoid prompting the bug in the first place by NOT renaming your lists or nested lists to a non-unique/duplicate identifier.